Movie about a guy who is alone in a spaceship and draws art with his food
I'm looking for a movie that I saw maybe 10 years ago or more on TV. It's probably american, sci-fi, starship-and-space-exploration type, and from what I vaguely remember:

things happen in space, inside the spaceship
the main guy character is awake and alone
something went wrong with the cryo-sleep feature, he woke up too soon (or didn't fall asleep at all because the cryo-sleep hatch didn't close well)
he has to entertain himself alone for so long
he eats these tubes of food (look like toothpaste)
when his teammates wake up, there's almost no food left
he drew some art with food on the ceiling because he was so bored
I'm feeling there's some woman character in the crew, one that's mad at him

It's not Passengers or Interstellar. Any ideas?

This most certainly Rocketman starring Harland Williams.
From Wikipedia:

Fred, along with Commander Overbeck, geologist Julie Ford (Jessica
  Lundy), and Ulysses, a trained chimpanzee, will look for fossils on
  Mars. To save on resources, crew members are put into "hypersleep" for
  eight months while the ship heads towards Mars. Ulysses purposely
  takes Fred's "hypersleep chamber" for his own and Fred has to sleep in
  Ulysses' chimp-shaped chamber. He sleeps for only 13 minutes and has
  to stay up for eight months.

It's during these eight months that Fred is awake and alone.  He goes stir crazy and starts painting with his food, which comes out of tubes.

this was one of my favorite movies when I was younger.  I also remembered the main actor because he is also in a movie called Down Periscope.  I had to find that movie to find his name so I could find this movie
